# Should we add a warning to tag legal

Tags: discussion, tags

Today I realized we have a tag [legal](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) on the main site with the excerpt

> Questions about legal problems which may arise during software development or questions about software law, patents and copyrights in general.

But we also have a custom close reason for questions that ask for *legal advise or aid*, which redirects users to our sister sites OpenSource.se and Law.se.

Should we add a warning notice to the tag [legal](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) that such questions are no longer a good fit here and that better answers should be expected at Law or OpenSource. I am thinking of something similar to the warning in the excerpt of [licensing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/licensing).

Comment: We already have something similar to this in the tag info.  Are you saying that you think we need the disclaimer in the excerpt as well? 
 https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/legal/info

Comment: @maple_shaft, yes I do. I updated the question te reflect that. I find the tag info really hard to access, so a warning there that a question with this tag is likely to be closed will be even less effective than a warning in the excerpt. With the warning in the excerpt, we have a better chance of saying you have been warned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest:

> [legal](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/legal/info)
>
> OFF TOPIC QUESTIONS ARE NOT SUPPORTED! Questions about legal matters, including software licensing, are off-topic here. ask a lawyer, or try the law stack exchange site.

However, please make the other forbidden tags consistent:

> [internship](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/internship/info)
>
> OFF TOPIC QUESTIONS ARE NOT SUPPORTED! Internship questions seeking career advice or discussions about workplace issues are off-topic on this site. We recommend avoiding asking any such questions here. Before asking on a different site in the stackexchange network, please review their site rules.

If we make the forbidden tags consistent it will make them easy to recognize as different from normal tags and provide a way to find them with a search.

Some more candidates:

- [education](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education)
- [teaching](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching)
- [learning](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning)
- [hiring](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hiring)
- [quotations](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quotations)
- [recruiting](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recruiting)
- [interview](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interview)
- [training](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/training)

Comment: Any idea how many of these tags we have?

Comment: @DocBrown I also found recruiting. Been trying to find more. I'd like some identical text string I could put in them all.

Comment: @DocBrown add [licensing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/licensing) to the list.

Comment: No, certain licensing question can still be on-topic here.

Comment: I found a SEDE query to search for "DO NOT USE" in the tag description, still evaluating which ones are really off-topic.

Comment: @DocBrown that search ability is what I don't want to lose.

Comment: @DocBrown nice work!

Comment: @DocBrown I've updated the tags in your list. Feel free to review them.

Answer (score 7):

I've taken a stab at a new Tag Excerpt.

> QUESTIONS ABOUT LEGAL MATTERS, INCLUDING SOFTWARE LICENSING, ARE OFF-TOPIC HERE. ASK A LAWYER, OR TRY THE LAW STACK EXCHANGE SITE.

My rationale:

1. Making it ALL CAPS increases the likelihood that an asker will see it.
2. The size of the excerpt is limited, and the longer it is, the less likely it is to be read.  I've tried to limit the information to only that which the asker needs.
3. Tag usage should be self-explanatory.

New users view tags as permission to ask.  Whenever possible, we need to try and limit this perception for off-topic tags, and the Tag Excerpt is as good a place as any.

Comment: All Caps shouldn't be necessary in my opinion - the only people who read the tag excerpt are those who already care about what it says

Comment: Then it's not going to matter either way, is it?

Comment: It does matter. Example user is unsure which tag to choose and opens up the description to see whether that `legal` tag makes sense or not, and whether there are any hints. With all caps, our example user feels yelled at. It is my personal opinion that the caps are adding little value but feel aggressive

Comment: If the excerpt offered formatting (bold, italics or blinking text, anything to grab attention) I would have used that instead, but it doesn't.